# LEFT JOIN not works after MATCH (...) AGAINST (... IN BOOLEAN MODE)

Tags: mysql, left-join, match-against

This query:

```
$user_mail_all=mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM `mailing` WHERE MATCH (resp) 
AGAINST ('$user_resp' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
OR `cor`='$username' ORDER BY `id` DESC  LIMIT ".$start.",".$per_page )
```

is working well, but next query:

```
$user_mail_all=mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM `mailing`WHERE MATCH (resp) 
AGAINST ('$user_resp' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
OR `cor`='$username' 
LEFT JOIN `mail_views` 
ON mailing.id=mail_views.lid 
AND mail_views.uid=".$_SESSION['uid']." 
ORDER BY `id` DESC  LIMIT ".$start.",".$per_page)
```

Results in an error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN mail_views ON mailing.id=mail_views.lid AND mail_views.uid=12 ORDER ' at line 1

Why?

Comment: I didn't want to answer as it might just be your typing in here but you need a space after the `mailing` and before the WHERE at the top.  If that is in your sql, please correct.  Again, I don't think it is your major problem here as stated in other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First JOIN then MATCH

```
$user_mail_all=mysql_query("SELECT * 
FROM `mailing`
LEFT JOIN `mail_views` 
ON mailing.id=mail_views.lid 
WHERE MATCH (resp) 
AGAINST ('$user_resp' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
OR `cor`='$username' 
AND mail_views.uid=".$_SESSION['uid']." 
ORDER BY `id` DESC  LIMIT ".$start.",".$per_page)
```

Answer (score 0):

in your query implementation of  left join is wrong...it should be:

select * from `Table1` **left join** `table2` where .....

so use this:

```
           $user_mail_all=
                mysql_query(
                             "SELECT * 
                                FROM `mailing`
                           LEFT JOIN `mail_views` 
                                 ON ( mailing.id=mail_views.lid 
                                     AND mail_views.uid=".$_SESSION['uid']".)
                              WHERE MATCH (resp) 
                                    AGAINST ('$user_resp' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
                                 OR `cor`='$username'
                           ORDER BY `id` DESC  LIMIT ".$start.",".$per_page);
```